# Regex to get particular string from a response

Tags: java, regex

I have a response like below

```
<adm:TargetCode key="urn:comcast:altcon:activityState">INACTIVE</adm:TargetCode>

  <adm:TargetCode key="urn:comcast:altcon:activityState">ACTIVE</adm:TargetCode>
```

From this using regex how can I get the strings `INACTIVE` and  `ACTIVE` strings.

I can use split methods, but it contains lots of code. To reduce the code I prefer to user regex. But how can I proceed with regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regex you can use:

```
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile(">(.*)<");
Matcher m1 = p1.matcher("<adm:TargetCode key=\"urn:comcast:altcon:activityState\">INACTIVE</adm:TargetCode>");
while (m1.find()) {
    System.out.println(m1.group(1));
}
```

Which outputs:

> INACTIVE

Explanation of the regex can be found [here](https://regex101.com/r/2Y79vW/1).

---

Using Strings the same can be achieved by:

```
String input = "<adm:TargetCode key=\"urn:comcast:altcon:activityState\">INACTIVE</adm:TargetCode>";
input = input.substring(input.indexOf(">") + 1, input.lastIndexOf("<"));
```

Comment: in my case response will contains lots of ACTIVE INACTIVE strings...about 100 lines

Comment: when i tried with code output is getting as ">INACTIVE</adm:TargetCode> <adm:TargetCode key="urn:comcast:altcon:activityState">ACTIVE< "

Comment: code tried: 
 ```    Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile(">(.*)<");
     Matcher m1 = p1
      .matcher("<adm:TargetCode key=\"urn:comcast:altcon:activityState\">INACTIVE</adm:TargetCode> <adm:TargetCode key=\"urn:comcast:altcon:activityState\">ACTIVE</adm:TargetCode>");
     while (m1.find()) {
  System.out.println(m1.group());
  
  
     }```

Comment: Use `Matcher m1 = p1.matcher("<adm:TargetCode key=\"urn:comcast:altcon:activityState\">INACTIVE</adm:TargetCode>\r\n" + 
    "\r\n" + 
    "  <adm:TargetCode key=\"urn:comcast:altcon:activityState\">ACTIVE</adm:TargetCode>");`

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to parse looks like html and you should prefer to use a html parser rather than regex.

You can use [JSoup](https://jsoup.org/) easily to parse the data like you have with following code,

```
String s = "<adm:TargetCode key=\"urn:comcast:altcon:activityState\">INACTIVE</adm:TargetCode>\r\n" + 
        "<adm:TargetCode key=\"urn:comcast:altcon:activityState\">ACTIVE</adm:TargetCode>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(s);
for (Element element : doc.getElementsByTag("adm:TargetCode")) {
    System.out.println(element.text());
}
```

Prints,

```
INACTIVE
ACTIVE
```

Although sometimes, regex can be used in case there are no nested structures present in the data you are trying to parse. For this case you can use this regex,

```
(?<=>)[^><\n]+(?=<)
```

Here, `(?<=>)` [positive look behind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) ensures the text matched is preceded by `>` and `(?=<)` positive look ahead ensures the text matched is followed by `<` while this character set `[^><\n]+` captures any character except `>` `<` and `\n` one or more times.

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oNmuZG/1/)**

Java code,

```
String s = "<adm:TargetCode key=\"urn:comcast:altcon:activityState\">INACTIVE</adm:TargetCode>\n<adm:TargetCode key=\"urn:comcast:altcon:activityState\">ACTIVE</adm:TargetCode>";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=>)[^><\\n]+(?=<)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Prints both the values in tags,

```
INACTIVE
ACTIVE
```

Also, the problem with other answer is, it uses `.*` in `>(.*)<` due to which, after matching a `>` it greedily matches any character including `<` or any that comes in middle of it as long as it can find a `<` somewhere down the line (which is present there at the end) and gives an unexpected match. To tackle this problem, it should use non-greedy version `.*?` instead of `.*` but even better is to use a negated character class [^><\n]+ like in my answer above as that gives better performance.